# Fluent NHibernate does not call my ClassMap<ControlEntity> class

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I use NHibernate for a dynamic website that its modules can be loaded dynamically, so when I want to build a sessionFactory, I use a way to find all assemblies and sort them with their dependencies
after all, I add them to Configuration instance I created and it works.
Now I want to change configuration type from hbm.xml files to fluent
I added below codes:

```
 sessionFactory =
    Fluently
    .Configure()
    .Database(
        FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(
            c =>  c.FromAppSetting("connectionString")
        )
    )
    .Mappings(
        m => m.AutoMappings.Add(
            AutoMap.Assemblies(
                new FarayanConfig(),
                assembliesArray
            )
        )
   ).BuildSessionFactory();
```

FarayanConfig is:

```
class FarayanConfig : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
    {
        return type.Name.EndsWith("Entity");
    }
    public override bool IsVersion(FluentNHibernate.Member member)
    {
    return member.Name == "Version";
    }
}
```

also I have a class in an assembly that will be loaded by this code (notice that assembly is not referenced, will be loaded dynamically) with a class named ControlEntity and also another class:

```
public class ControlEntityMap : ClassMap<ControlEntity>
{
    public ControlEntityMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Properties).Component(c => {
            c.Map(v => v.Culture);
            c.Map(v => v.Name);
            c.Map(v => v.Value);
        });
    }
}
```

now the problem is constructor of ControlEntityMap will not execute!
what I must do?

Answer (score 0):

Because of you are trying to use AutoMap.
You can use something like this:

```
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.Load("your assembly name")))
```

**Update:**

You are doing right by ovverride DefaultAutomappingConfiguration for this situation but also you are trying to AutoMap all classes which ones end with "Entity" and your class which one you want to ignore it from AutoMap also ends with "Entity". I think you can seperate your classes in different namespaces and declare it in your ShouldMap property.

And there are some information in FluentNhibenate Wiki:

> You can ignore base types by simply excluding them from your
>   ShouldMap(Type) method, that's sometimes the cleanest option; however,
>   if you want to be a bit more explicit you can use the IgnoreBase
>   method.
>
> After AutoMap.AssemblyOf() we need to alter the conventions
>   that the auto mapper is using so it can identify our base-class.
>
> AutoMap.AssemblyOf(cfg)   .IgnoreBase();
>
> We've added the IgnoreBase call which simply instructs the
>   automapper to ignore the Entity class; you can chain this call as many
>   times as needed.

Comment: How can I mix AutoMap with Manual map? I mean I want to use auto map for all entities but for some entities, create ClassMap<entity> classes?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I thought I found where the problem is. Fluent does not detected collections of composite types (in AutoMap), for example, if I use IList<AnotherEntity>, no problem, and also if I use IList<string>, but for IList<PropertyValue>, it throws exception "Association references unmapped class: Farayan.Web.Portal.PropertyValue". In another place in StackOverflow, I found a discussion about collection of primitive types that solved by upgrading Fluent, but not for composite types